# Chain observables in ViewModel for fetch but leave as independent properties

Tags: swift, mvvm, mapkit, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

I have a `MapViewModel` for my `MapViewController`.

I have a `MapObjectService` with a function `fetchMapObjects(currentLocation: CLLocation)` that returns an `Observable<MapObjects>`

In the MapViewModel I have:

```
var currentLocation: Observable<CLLocation?>
var mapObjects: Observable<MapObjects>
```

I can init the current location like this:

```
currentLocation = locationManager.rx.didUpdateLocations.map( { locations in
        return locations.filter() { loc in
            return loc.horizontalAccuracy < 20
            }.first
    })
```

How can I efficiently init both properties so the `fetchMapObjects()` uses the currentLocation to set the `mapObjects` property?

My plan is to bind those properties to the mapView in `MapViewController` to show the map objects as pins and the current location.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
currentLocation = locationManager.rx.didUpdateLocations.map( { locations in
   return locations.filter() { loc in
      return loc.horizontalAccuracy < 20
   }.first
})

mapObjects = currentLocation.flatMap { loc in
   return MapObjectService.fetchMapObjects(currentLocation: loc)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can define `mapObjects` as a *continuation* of the `currentLocation` stream:

Something like this:

```
currentLocation = locationManager.rx.didUpdateLocations.map { locations in
    return locations.first(where: { location -> Bool in
        return location.horizontalAccuracy < 20
    })
}

mapObjects = currentLocation.flatMapLatest { location -> Observable<MapObjects> in
    guard let location = location else {
        return Observable<String>.empty()
    }
    return fetchMapObjects(currentLocation: location)
}
```

That way, each time the `currentLocation` observable emits a location it will be used for the `fetchMapObjects` call.

I've used `flatMapLatest` here instead of `flatMap` in order to discard any previous calls to the `fetchMapObjects` if a new location is emitted before the call finishes.

You can also define filtering for the `currentLocation` before the `flatMapLatest` in case you want to ignore some of them, e.g. when the distance is too short from the previous one.

Now you can just subscribe to your `mapObjects` observable and handle any `MapObjects` that are emitted.

```
mapObjects.subscribe(onNext: { objects in
    // handle mapObjects here
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation.  That did it!

Comment: @MayNotBe you're welcome! However, just to be fair, joern answered the question before me and basically said the same thing I did :) So if you want, you could mark his answer instead of mine. I'll take an upvote maybe? ;)

Comment: Thanks @iska ! Frankly, your answer is better than mine and it at least deserves another upvote.

Comment: @joern Thank you too! Cheers :)